# Grails: looking for a dynamic tab

Tags: grails

Is there a tab control in Grails that has the following features:

- Programmatically open new tabs
- Programmatically select tabs
- Each open tab has an id to identify it
- Each open tab has a flag to indicate if it's closable

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

no there is not, why not just use jquery tab? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see a flag to set a tab closable, any idea?